# 'IBOutlet' property has non-optional type 'UIButton'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

It's a simple IBOutlet (straight from the Apple developer docs). It gives me the error "'IBOutlet' property has non-optional type 'UIButton'" and I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can also be-

```
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
```

or

```
    @IBOutlet var weak button: UIButton! (in case you are not doing view unloading)
```

if you are using XCODE 6 Beta 4

Comment: I found that making it something like @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel! = nil solved all my problems

Comment: Is there an explanation why ! is required?

Answer (score 12):

It should be like that (in Beta 3 or before):

```
@IBOutlet var button: UIButton?
```

IBOutlets must be optionals so place a `?` behind the type.

Comment: Where does Apple require that IBOutlets must be optional? The compiler accepts `@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!` alright.

Comment: @Drux Look at the checked answer. This is only valid for Beta 3 or below.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel! = nil

     override func viewDidLoad() {

           super.viewDidLoad()

           name.text="i m a label"
     }
 }
```

This code working fine

But when i replace @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel? it is not working.

Comment: You would have to unwrap the optional: `name?.text = "i'm a label"`